# in automator how can I make a hotkey to insert string

Tags: hotkeys, automator

What I want to do seems simple, but all the automator docs cover different functionalities.  I have a number of strings that I have to input repeatedly throughout the day and I want to make hotkeys to insert them wherever I am (safari, chrome, terminal, etc).  Is there a very straightforward way to do this in automator?

Comment: this makes it sound like what I want to do is more involved than I thought.  It's quite old, though! [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1215969?start=0&tstart=0)